# Using useEffect to access the window object in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I needed to access  `window.localStorage` in my Next.js app but since Next.js allows both server-side and client-side rendering, when i tried to set the default value of a state using the local storage like this:

```
useState(window.localStorage.getItem("tag"))
```

it would throw an error saying `window` was undefined.
In order to find a way to make it work, i used a useEffect and set the value of the state once the component fully rendered, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(localStorage.getItem("tag"));
  }, []);
```

But i am not sure if this was the right approach. Is this a good solution or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: @motto that didn't work, that's why i was forced to use the useEffect

Comment: @motto that approach could lead to hydration errors due to mismatches between what was rendered on the server and on client-side's first render.

Comment: True @ivanatias I will delete the bad comment

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

Due to hydration, when the component is created at the backend, it doesn't have access to `window` object. And seems to me `useEffect` isn't run at the backend. I guess backend only assembles the first frame (mount) render.

Thus `useEffect` is the way to dodge this issue. Of course people can also check whether `window` exists, but I feel `useEffect` is more elegant.